# How to identify Facebook app developer by id number?

Tags: facebook, ownership, owner

We've created an app last year and are still using it. Problem is now that no one at the office can see the app when visiting developers.facebook.com.

Q:
Who is the 'owner' of our app with id 273488249346057

We tried every e-mailaddres of the office with no result... out of options, need some advice how to retreive this info so we know with what user/e-mail we have to login

Comment: Got an app access token? Then you could just read the roles, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#roles

Answer (score 2):

If you have the secret key of the application you can retrieve the developers by this graph api call

https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/roles?access_token=APP_ID|SECRET_KEY

The whole list of information you can retrieve for specific application you can find here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

Otherwise you cant get developers list